# Eager loading child collection with NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, eager-loading, querying

I want to load root entities and eager load all it's child collection and aggregate members.

Have been trying to use the `SetFetchMode` in FluentNHibernate, but I am getting duplicates in one of the child collection since I have a depth of 3 levels. `DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer` unfortunately only removes the root duplications.

```
return Session.CreateInvoiceBaseCriteria(query, archived)
    .AddOrder(new Order(query.Order, query.OrderType == OrderType.ASC))
    .SetFetchMode("States", FetchMode.Eager)
    .SetFetchMode("Attestations", FetchMode.Eager)
    .SetFetchMode("AttestationRequests", FetchMode.Eager)
    .SetFetchMode("AttestationRequests.Reminders", FetchMode.Eager)
    .SetResultTransformer(new DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer())
    .List<Invoice>();
```

Could I use multi queries or something similar to archive this?

Furthermore, wouldn't this approach result in unnecessarily huge result sets from the database?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8):

Found a solution but it isn't pretty. First I go and find all the Invoice IDs, then I use them in the multiquery and then at the end filtering the results through a HashedSet. Because of the large number of items sometimes i couldn't use the normalt Restriction.In and was forced to send it as a string.

Any suggested tweaks?

```
var criteria = Session.CreateInvoiceBaseCriteria(query, archived)
    .SetProjection(Projections.Id());

var invoiceIds = criteria.List<int>();
if (invoiceIds.Count > 0)
{
    var joinedIds = JoinIDs(criteria.List<int>()); // To many ids to send them as parameters.

    var sql1 = string.Format("from Invoice i inner join fetch i.States where i.InvoiceID in ({0}) order by i.{1} {2}", joinedIds, query.Order, query.OrderType.ToString());
    var sql2 = string.Format("from Invoice i inner join fetch i.AttestationRequests where i.InvoiceID in ({0})", joinedIds);
    var sql3 = string.Format("from Invoice i inner join fetch i.Attestations where i.InvoiceID in ({0})", joinedIds);

    var invoiceQuery = Session.CreateMultiQuery()
        .Add(sql1)
        .Add(sql2)
        .Add(sql3);

    var result = invoiceQuery.List()[0];

    return new UniqueFilter<Invoice>((ICollection)result);
}

return new List<Invoice>();
```

Comment: That is odd, Attestations are fetched as single queries.

Comment: +1, It is actually (and unfortunately) the best way (performance-wise) to achieve this.

Comment: I'm in a similar situation (trying to pull in 3 levels at once).  Although your solution gets rid of the duplicates, it only appears to be 2 levels deep.  Your original question included a 3rd level down called "AttestationRequests.Reminders" that is not included in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question: yes, it results in huge resultsets.

I suggest to:

- just naively write your queries without eager fetching
- On certain places, put an eager fetch, but only one per query
- if you really get performance problems which you can't solve with indexes or by enhance queries and mapping strategies, use your solution with the multiple queries.

Answer (score 0):

While it might not be exactly what you are looking for, I would recommend looking at this article:

[Eager loading aggregate with many child collections](http://nhibernate.info/blog/2008/09/06/eager-loading-aggregate-with-many-child-collections.html)

If you look around the rest of that site you will find even more posts that discuss eager loading and other great nHibernate stuff.

Comment: Indeed a good article, but unsure if I can apply it to my situation. The solution described in the article about eager loading a specific root entity, my problem is that I want to eager load a collection of root entities. If I would use MultiCritera I need to find a way to connect all the different queries without specifying a specific entity. Suggestions how that can be made?

Comment: That example has only one additional hierarchy level, but no grandchildren, for which MultiQuery/MultiCriteria seems to be quite useless, since later queries can't reference results from previous queries (like Query#1: select rootObjects r left join fetch children c where ...; Query#2: select grandchildren g where parent in c).