# NHibernate LazyLoading

Tags: nhibernate, jqgrid, lazy-loading, jqgrid-asp.net

For an ASP.Net project I'm using (Fluent) NHibernate for the persistence and JQGrid for displaying the data in a table. But when I want to use the AutoComplete feature of JQGrid I get an `System.ArgumentException: Column 'HibernateLazyInitializer' does not belong with this table.` while obtaining the data in an AJAX Request.
But this error occurs only sporadically and when some kind of proxyclass is used in the list. Therefore I think it has something to with the lazyloading of NHibernate.

```
protected new void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     base.Page_Load(sender, e);
     _jqAutoComplete.DataSource = Session.CreateCriteria<Domain.Brand>()
            .List<Domain.Brand>();
     _jqAutoComplete.DataBind();
  }
```

Usually the lazyloading is a pretty cool feature. Only in this case it leads to an error and therefore I don't want to disable it in the whole project. So, is there a way of modifying the CreateCriteria for not using LazyLoading but EagerLoading in this one case?
Or is there something else I'm missing? 
If there is a good tutorial for understanding LazyLoading I would be glad too.

Comment: Which "AutoComplete" feature you mean and how you use it? That is `_jqAutoComplete` object? Do you use probably commercial version of jqGrid from http://www.trirand.net/?

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/937388/eager-loading-child-collection-with-nhibernate

Comment: Yes. I use the commerical version with the class called `Trirand.Web.UI.WebControls.JQAutoComplete`.

Comment: Do you tried to post the question in [the trirand.net forum](http://www.trirand.net/forum/)?

Comment: Nein hab ich noch nicht. Ich denke, aber dass das ein Problem von meinem NHibernate-Code ist und nicht unbedingt von jqGrid. Außerdem hab ich nicht das Gefühl, dass ich beim trirand-forum brauchbare Hilfe bekommen könnte.

Comment: verstehe... Ich kann leider nur bei free open source jqGrid helfen. Weder NHibernate noch commercial version von jqGrid kenne ich. Mach's gut!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem differently. Now I'm converting the Domain-Object into the corresponding object from the ViewModel. I'm using [ValueInjecter](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/) for accomplishing the mapping.

```
protected new void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     base.Page_Load(sender, e);

     var objList = service.getList<Domain.Brand>();
     IList<V> list = new List<ViewModel.Brand>();

     foreach (var el in objList)
     {
        var brand = new ViewModel.Brand();
        list.Add(brand.InjectFrom<FlatLoopValueInjection>(el));
     }

     _jqAutoComplete.DataSource = list;
     _jqAutoComplete.DataBind();
  }
```

That solution works for me but I'm not totally happy with that.